# How to get a static circular frame shape for other bodies in the world in box2D?

Tags: javascript, box2d

I am learning box2DWeb for JavaScript and HTML5 canvas.
I was wondering how to create a circular frame with box2d shapes so that other shapes will be inside the hole and can be moved along its curve while staying inside it ?

Comment: You can arrange edges (polygons created by SetAsEdge) in a circular ring.